# Swift/Cocoa: launchApplication(at:options:configuration:) and catching errors

Tags: swift, cocoa, documentation, appkit

So... I want to launch an application at a given URL using this function. The problem is, the developer documentation says:

> **Parameters**
>
> *url*
>
> The application URL.
>
> *options*
>
> Options to use when launching the application. See
> NSWorkspace.LaunchOptions for possible values.
>
> *configuration*
>
> A dictionary containing the configuration options. This
> dictionary can be used to pass additional options to the app. Possible
> key-value pairs are described in Workspace Launch Configuration
> Options. The configuration dictionary may be empty, in which case
> default behavior applies.
>
> *error*
>
> Returns, by-reference, the error if the application was unable
> to be launched. You may specify nil for this parameter if you do not
> want the error information.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> If the app is already running, and *newInstance* is not
> specified in the options dictionary, then a reference to the existing
> app is returned; otherwise a new application reference is returned. If
> the application could not be launched, *nil* is returned and the error
> is specified in *error*.

The problem is, that this doesn't match with the function signature at all, which is:

```swift
func launchApplication(at url: URL, options: NSWorkspace.LaunchOptions = [], configuration: [NSWorkspace.LaunchConfigurationKey : Any]) throws -> NSRunningApplication
```

Where the hell am I supposed to specify said error?

Comment: Read the rest of that documentation where it talks about handling errors in Swift. BTW - you state it doesn't match at all. But it matches exactly except for the error so please clarify your question.

Comment: I might have been slightly hyperbolic but you're splitting hairs.

I guess I'm not really asking so much about catching the error as I am about propagating it to the user.

Comment: The parameter names match exactly. There is `url`, `options`, and `configuration`.

Comment: @rmaddy is not splitting hairs. All Cocoa methods that have an error parameter have their function signature changed so that the error parameter is removed and the function is turned into a throwing function. You must catch the error and handle it. See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 2):

Except for the error handling, the parameters mentioned in the documentation exactly match the actual method. Both have `url`, `options`, and `configuration`. Though, thanks to Swift's ability to have argument labels, you use `at` with the `url` parameter when actually calling the method.

Most Objective-C APIs that have a last parameter of `NSError **error` are translated in Swift to an API that has no error parameter. Instead, they declare that they `throw`.

If you read the rest of the documentation for the method you quoted, you will see:

> **Handling Errors In Swift**:
>
> In Swift, this method returns a nonoptional result and is marked with the `throws` keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure.
>
> You call this method in a `try` expression and handle any errors in the `catch` clauses of a `do` statement, as described in [Error Handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) in [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/) and [About Imported Cocoa Error Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/about_imported_cocoa_error_parameters).

You handle the error as follows:

```
do {
    // pass real options and configuration as needed
    try someWorkspace.launcApplication(at: someURL, options: [], configuration: [:])
} catch {
    // handle error here as needed
    print(error)
}
```